# SQL Update from one table to another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have looked up how to do this and found answers 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737221/update-msaccess-table-from-another-access-table-using-sql).

I have set up a basic MS Access 2013 database to test this and have tried both solutions.

When I try to run the below:

```
UPDATE 
Tbl1 as A
INNER JOIN tbl2 AS B ON A.userID = B.UserID 
SET A.userID = B.[UserID];
```

I get a message box saying that I am **about to update 0 rows**. Even though there is UserID data in tbl2.

When I try:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.[UserID] = B.[UserID]
FROM tbl1 A, tbl2 B WHERE A.[UserID] = B.[UserID]
```

I get a "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"

I did note that someone mentioned in the comments that the second solution wouldn't work in Access 2013 but like I said, the first solution isn't working either.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try

UPDATE tbl1
SET userid = (SELECT userid
               FROM tbl2)

Comment: Hi @Hans, yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

UPDATE tbl1
SET userid = (SELECT userid
               FROM tbl2)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. When I try this I get "Operation must use an updateable query"? 
Also I would like to be able to amend the Update query to copy over multiple columns once I've got it working

Comment: ok, so do you have data in tbl1 or are you transferering data to tbl1 from tbl2

Comment: There is historical data in tbl1 but I would like to append additional rows onto it with the data from tbl2

Comment: then use
INSERT INTO tbl1
SELECT * FROM tbl2;

or

INSERT INTO tbl1
(userid)
SELECT userid
FROM tbl2;

Comment: Ahh! Brilliant. That works. Sorry, I realise now that I was getting update and insert into mixed up. Thank you for your help

Comment: please give me a vote if this solved your problems, I always get remarks on misspellings and questions marks and so on...

Answer (score 2):

> "I get a message box saying that I am about to update 0 rows. Even though there is UserID data in tbl2."

Because if updating where `A.userID = B.[UserID]` then `A.userID = B.UserID` updates 0 rows.

If you were joining on something like a `userName` then you might be doing something.

```
UPDATE Tbl1 as A
INNER JOIN tbl2 AS B ON A.userName = B.userName 
SET A.userID = B.[UserID];
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I was being an idiot. Hans has shown me that I was getting mixed up between an UPDATE and INSERT INTO statement. I should've explained more clearly in my question what I was trying to do. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

As to what i see here is you are trying to set the values of columns which you are also using in the where clause. While in the answer you quoted, the columns being set is different than those using in the where clause, **hence 0  rows update message.**